# PHP variables in function argument is not working

Tags: php, function, variables, arguments

I've retried solving this, by using a condition and a default attribute as recommended.

User-generated data is declared before to $Variable_1:

```
<?php 

$Variable_1 = 'abc123!' //The user inputs the data

if ($booleanvalue == true) { // User selects if they've put data
name($user_data, $Variable_0 = $Variable_1 );
}

//Then the function will use the user's data from $Variable_1

function name($user_data, $Variable_0 = null) {

//Other code...

}

  $Variable_2 = name($user_data);
  $data['variable_2'] = $Variable_2;

?>
```

Is it possible to have $Variable_0 pre-declared and then put as an argument?

Comment: What is the point of both passing it as an argument and making it global? Either do one or the other. But it seems to me what you're after are [default argument values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

Comment: Okay, I've added the default attribute and it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few mistakes in your code. and I don't think that you can use a function named name.

you could do it this way for example:

```
<?php

$Variable_1 = 'abc123!';


function test($data) {
    
    global $Variable_1;
    
    //Other calculations...
    return $Variable_1 .  $data;
    
}
$testdata = "huhu";
$Variable_2 = test($testdata);
$data['variable_2'] = $Variable_2;


echo $data['variable_2'];
```

?>

Comment: I've changed the code a little bit, do you think this will solve my problem the best way, as it now puts the correct data into $Variable_0?

Comment: Nope, sorry, but so it will never work. 1) if you proove a bool var then you need to proove against === and not ==. 2) the assignment from $Variable= = $Variable1 inside the name-function will not work too.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment by El_Vanja, but you can access a global variable through the magic $GLOBALS array anywhere.

```php
<?php

// what you might actually want
function name($variable = 'abc123!')
{
    // if no value is passed into the function the default value 'abc123!' is used
}


$variable = 'abc123!';

// what you could do
function name2($variable)
{
    // $variable can be any value

    // $globalVariable is 'abc123!';
    $globalVariable = $GLOBALS['variable'];
}
```

I'd also like to point out that currently you have no way of controlling what type of data is passed to the function. [You might consider adding types.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php)

```php
<?php

<?php

// string means the variable passed to the function has to be a ... well string
function name(string $variable = 'abc123!'): void 
{
    // void means the function doesn't return any values
}


name(array()); // this throws a TypeError
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I thought it would be easier to use a default attribute as you said.

Comment: @Joboy2212 So this anwsered your question or ... ?

Comment: I've added a boolean variable to a conditional statement and a default attribute to the function and it works just fine, but I have no idea if this the cleanest way of doing things